# Xamarin forms navigation back button

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation, toolbar, back-button

I am a newbie in xamarin forms app development, currently, I am facing an issue in overriding the toolbar back button onclick. In ios, I am able to achieve but in android its not working can anyone help me out on how to achieve this in my project.

Comment: Would you mind post your project on the github?

Comment: This project is an enterprise I don't have permission to upload the project anywhere. Can you please help me on this, how to override back button click of the toolbar.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621880/mvvmcross-soft-back-button-does-not-work-when-using-drawerlayout/49645119#49645119) will give you some help, it is difficult to answer if there are nor related codes.

Comment: Hi, so have you tried `Toolbar.NavigationClick += Toolbar_NavigationClick;` in the link?

Comment: In my main activity, I am not able to get Toolbar.NavigationClick its showing error. Can you tell me where i should use this method as i m building xamarin forms app

Comment: Can you get the `Toolbar` object? Show some codes, please.

Comment: public class MainActivity : global:: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

           
           
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

            FlowListView.Init();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
                     

        }

Comment: Yes, but it can't help us to solve your problem, can you make a demo to reproduce the problem? O~ May be you have forgot to use `FindViewById` method?

Comment: Actually when i am doing this my app is getting crash             Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar 
                = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Yeah, good, so what exception is it?

Comment: Invalid cast exception

Comment: Ok, i have tested it again. Please delete your bin and obj folder in your Xamarin.Android project, and restart your VS.

Comment: now my app is not getting crashed but home toolbar is only getting displayed in the entire app and also in toolbar there is no back button

Comment: If the page is the first page, there is no back button, you can use [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#creating-the-root-page) to navigate your page. And then in your second page, there will be back button.

Comment: This [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/BackButton) will explain it.

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Can I post an answer for your question?

Comment: so basically you are asking me to create a toolbar kind of design in the layout and use an arrow image and set button event?

Comment: No, `overriding the toolbar back button onclick.`, you have already had the toolbar. I just suggest you to add Click event on the toolbar. So, you still can't solve the problem?

Comment: The thing happening here I am not getting back arrow key in my toolbar so how do I set onClick?

Answer (score 1):

By default it works on iOS and on **Android physical back button** only. If you want to also support the navigation bar button, you need to use custom platform logic. Take a look on this blog post: [Let’s Override Navigation Bar back button click in Xamarin For](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/). He creates a common content page with custom action for back button:

```
 public class CoolContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Back button click overriden custom action
        /// </summary>
        public Action CustomBackButtonAction { get; set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty =
               BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(EnableBackButtonOverride),
               typeof(bool),
               typeof(CoolContentPage),
               false);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets Custom Back button overriding state
        /// </summary>
        public bool EnableBackButtonOverride
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then he calls **CustomBackAction** inside **OnOptionsItemSelected** method in Anroid code.

Comment: I have been through this post earlier in android main activity support toolbar is not working. Its getting crash

Answer (score 1):

Best way to intercept Back Navigation ( Navigation in general ) would be by adding your NavigationPageRenderer  so you can control the events and cancel or redirect them, look at my answer [How to intercept Navigation Bar Back Button Clicked in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696595/how-to-intercept-navigation-bar-back-button-clicked-in-xamarin-forms/63198797#63198797)

Answer (score 0):

I came to this post with same question about Xamarin forms navigation back button and later discovered that since `Xamarin.Forms Shell` this is done easily by overriding the OnNavigating method in the `AppShell.xaml.cs` file as I have done here:

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure it's safe to examine the current page
    if ((Shell.Current != null) &&
        (Shell.Current.CurrentPage != null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Source} {Shell.Current.Title}");
        if (
            // Detect Back Navigation
            e.Source == ShellNavigationSource.Pop &&

            // Cancel or Not, based on (for example) the Title of the current page.
            (Shell.Current.Title != "My Main Page"))
        {
            e.Cancel();
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
    }
    base.OnNavigating(e);
}
```

In case anyone else stumbles upon, I put a sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/app-shell-proto-21.git) of what worked for me for Android and iOS both.