# Override navbar back button click on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there any way to show an alert msg before clicking navbar back icon & exiting the page.
I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72501123/how-do-i-register-an-arrow-click-handler-in-the-navigation-page) but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture the back button click the Action Bar in android platform, you can try to override the `OnOptionsItemSelected()` in the `MainActivity` class, which allows us to capture the navigation bar’s back button click.

Please follow up the following steps:

1.create a base contentpage `CoolContentPage.cs`

```
public class CoolContentPage: ContentPage 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Back button click overriden custom action
    /// </summary>
    public Action CustomBackButtonAction { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(
           nameof(EnableBackButtonOverride),
           typeof(bool),
           typeof(CoolContentPage),
           false);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Custom Back button overriding state
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableBackButtonOverride
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

2.override the `OnOptionsItemSelected()` event in `MainActivity` class in order to capture the nav bar back button click in Android for Xamarin Forms.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity 
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar
            = this.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        // check if the current item id 
        // is equals to the back button id
        if (item.ItemId == 16908332) // xam forms nav bar back button id
        {
            // retrieve the current xamarin 
            // forms page instance
            var currentpage = (CoolContentPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.
                 MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

            // check if the page has subscribed to the custom back button event
            if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
            {
                // invoke the Custom back button action
                currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
                // and disable the default back button action
                return false;
            }

            // if its not subscribed then go ahead 
            // with the default back button action
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // since its not the back button 
            //click, pass the event to the base
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        // this is really not necessary, but in Android user has both Nav bar back button 
        // and physical back button, so its safe to cover the both events

        var currentpage = (CoolContentPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.
            MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

        if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
        {
            currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Here, we need to create  `Toolbar.xml` in folder `layout`

Toolbar.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

3.In xamarin forms,we can use `CoolContentPage` we created above as a XAML page in Xamarin Forms solution:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<xfbackbtnapp:CoolContentPage  xmlns:xfbackbtnapp="clr-namespace:XFBackBtnApp"
                               xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XFBackBtnApp.MainPage"
             EnableBackButtonOverride="False"
             Title="Home Page"
             BackgroundColor="#00bfff"                  
                               >

    <StackLayout
    Spacing="20"
    Padding="20,10,20,10"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" >

        <Label Text="Welcome to Navigation Bar Back button Click overriding in Xamarin Forms!"
           FontSize="20"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           TextColor="White"/>

        <Button Text="Open Next Page" FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="OpenPageButton_OnClicked"></Button>

    </StackLayout>

</xfbackbtnapp:CoolContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : CoolContentPage 
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenPageButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
}
```

**Page1.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<xfbackbtnapp:CoolContentPage  xmlns:xfbackbtnapp="clr-namespace:XFBackBtnApp" 
                               xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              EnableBackButtonOverride="False"
             BackgroundColor="#00bfff"
             Title="Page 1"
             x:Class="XFBackBtnApp.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
    Spacing="20"
    Padding="20,10,20,10"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" >

            <Label Text="Ok, this is just a normal Page! Click next Page to see the Navigation Bar Back button click overridden behavior..."
           FontSize="20"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           TextColor="White"/>

            <Button Text="Open Next Page" FontSize="15" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="OpenPageButton_OnClicked"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</xfbackbtnapp:CoolContentPage>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Page1 : CoolContentPage 
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenPageButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<xfbackbtnapp:CoolContentPage  xmlns:xfbackbtnapp="clr-namespace:XFBackBtnApp"
                               xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XFBackBtnApp.Page2"
             EnableBackButtonOverride="True"
             BackgroundColor="#00bfff"         
             Title="Page 2"
                               
                               >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
    Spacing="20"
    Padding="20,10,20,10"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" >

            <Label Text="This is the cool page, which has the Navigation Bar Back button click overriden. How go ahead and click that Back button! ;)"
           FontSize="20"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           TextColor="White"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</xfbackbtnapp:CoolContentPage>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```
   public partial class Page2 : CoolContentPage 
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (EnableBackButtonOverride)
        {
            this.CustomBackButtonAction = async () =>
            {
                var result = await this.DisplayAlert(null,
                    "Hey wait now! are you sure " +
                    "you want to go back?",
                    "Yes go back", "Nope");

                if (result)
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

1.Here,I added property `EnableBackButtonOverride="True"` to the root of `Page2.xaml`, then if we can press the back button of the `Toolbar` on the top of the page or press the soft back button of our Phone, a `DisplayAlert` will pop up.

2.If you want to achieve this function in Ios,you can check article [Override Navigation Bar back button click in Xamarin Forms](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/comment-page-1/#comment-1167).

Comment: Thanks for replying & for your time. I've tried this solution before but toolbar obj always null 
`AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar  = this.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);` Do you have any idea how to fix ?

Comment: Have you added file `Toolbar.xml` in folder `layout` of android platform?

Comment: And remember to add code  `ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;` above code `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `MainActivity.cs` .

Comment: ya, all code is added. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74949702/androidx-appcompat-widget-toolbar-always-null) plz

Comment: You can get the sample code [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/FormBackBtnDemo).

Comment: Hi @EmanAshraf, have you achieved the function of pressing the back button?

Comment: At first, Thanks for continuous support. Secondly, I've a problem with OnOptionsItemSelected, It's not called. I'm using MasterDetailPage.